# Android proguard rule gives error with twilio client sdk

Tags: android, gradle, twilio, proguard

I have added the Twilio client SDK with the following proguard rules

```
 # Twilio Client
 -keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
 # Apache HttpClient
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

When that's added I get the following set of error message

```
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebViewClient depends on program class android.net.http.SslError
Warning:there were 3 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

To suppress the error I have added these set of rules

```
-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient
```

When I do the above I get these set of errors

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(android.support.design.widget.o) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
```

which breaks the apk build. Any sort of help will be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
> Error:(android.support.design.widget.o) that doesn't come with an
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
> ```

To solve innerclass issue add this in your proguard file:

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: Can you please brief more on the solution?